# how to create heroku app for hosting telegram bot with node js

Tags: heroku

I want to a free host to create an App but, so I choose heroku, I download and installed heroku cli but I give this error when I commond this line of code in my commond prompt. how can I fix this error and create the heroku app?

my commond :heroku create
warning I get first: »   Warning: heroku update available from 7.69.1 to 8.1.9.

Creating app... !
!    ETIMEDOUT: connect ETIMEDOUT 34.226.106.136:443

I try again the prompt again and again and think maybe it's happened because of the bad connection of my internet connectio, but still heppend and I except to create the heroku app